# Me sale este error, usando nodejs, express, handlebars: Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided

Tags: javascript, nodejs

> He puesto la extensión y el proveedor, pero al entrar al servidor localhost, es cuando sale el error,

```
app.set('port',process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname,'views'));
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
    defaultLayout:'main',
    extname:'.hbs'

}));
app.set('view.engine', 'hbs');
```

Comment: exhbs es la constante de uso de express-handlebars: const exphbs=require('express-handlebars')

Comment: Cambia esta línea: `app.set('view.engine', 'hbs');` por esto otro: `app.set('view engine', 'hbs');`. Como puedes apreciar, te dejaste un punto (`.`) entre `view` y `engine`. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero ya le cambie, con y sin punto en esa parte y sigue apareciendo el error

Comment: Uy, espera que lo replico.

Comment: Sip, es como indican en la respuesta, un error de tipeo. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

espero ayudar, creo que tienes un fallo como dice el compañero en donde dice "view.engine" y en donde dice "hbs":

```
app.set('port',process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname,'views'));
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
    defaultLayout:'main',
    extname:'.hbs'

}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
```

Linea original "view.engine","hbs" :

```
app.set('view.engine', 'hbs');
```